# A simple question about SVN

Tags: svn

When I use SVN client, should I use as local repository:

- the files that i'm currently editing (i.e. my Eclipse project)
- or should I create an intermediary local copy, and not the files I'm editing ?

The reason I'm asking this is that I often need to update my local repository before to submit changes.

When I need to update it don't I overwrite my local changes ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the files you're editing - if there's a conflict, you're going to have to resolve it anyway, and SVN will [help you do so](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/04/how-to-resolve-subversion-conflicts/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't create any intermediate copies. SVN will merge your changes with any remote changes other repository users made since the last update.